# Comparing entity against previous entity in views

Tags: views

Say my view lists people and their salaries using data from their profile..

```
Abby, 10000, O
Amelie, 10000, O
Alan, 15000, O
Ben, 15000, O
Bertie, 20000, O
Boris, 20000, O
Carl, 20000, O
Carol, 25000, O
Derek, 25000, O
```

How can I change the third column to an X when the salary changes?

```
Abby, 10000, X
Amelie, 10000, O
Alan, 15000, X
Ben, 15000, O
Bertie, 20000, X
Boris, 20000, O
Carl, 20000, O
Carol, 25000, X
Derek, 25000, O
```

I'm guessing I do it in hook_views_pre_render($view), but there are so many variables/objects in the $view, I don't know where to start.

I don't think it matters, but I'm using views_data_export to output this into a CSV.

Comment: Maybe you can try Rules module?

Comment: Fun fact - there was [a support request](https://drupal.org/node/1390212) in Views issue queue, but got closed without an answer. Consider reopening it with use case you provided here.

Comment: Do you actually need the third column? Why is it not sufficient to group by salary in the display?

Comment: Yes I do need it in the third column.  It's not a styling/grouping issue.  It's needed for another automated process that reads the CSV.

Comment: What do you mean by "changed"? Changed from what?

Comment: Instead of trying to get the previous row, what about store the current row in a $_SESSION variable and during the next row compare its value with the previous stored data

Answer (score 0):

Probably late by now, but have you tried using revisions? You can pull in individual fields that has any revision.