# Create a views chart that display the percentage progress of some tasks over each week

Tags: views, charts

I have successfully created multiple charts in views using Google Chart Tools, but this one is tricky;

Here are the entry dates:

- I have multiple tasks that are Nodes and each one of them have a 'date field' for planning date and a 'date field' for date actually completed.
- I need to create a chart in views that display the percentage of tasks planned and completed over each week. This chart will be linear and it has to display the values in a progression.

I've managed to get percentage for each week for both planned and completed date, knowing of course the total number of tasks. Also i have created the linear chart that display the weeks number on the X-axis and the amount of percent on the Y-axis, but the values are displayed independent for each week and not in progression as I want.

Example:

Week 35: 3 task planned (30%), 2 completed (20%); Week 36: 3 tasks planned (30%), 3 completed (30%); Week 37: 4 tasks planned (40%), 3 completed (30%). Total: 100% planned, 80% completed.

The chart values must be displayed as:

- Week 35: Planned 30% / Completed 20%;
- Week 36: Planned 60% / Completed 50%;
- Week 37: Planned 100% / Completed 80%;

I need a function that adds the previous value to the next one to display the chart progressively until 100%.

Suggestions?

Comment: Is your need basically like [Comparing entity against previous entity in views](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83874/comparing-entity-against-previous-entity-in-views)?

Comment: I don't think is quite like that; in views it's easy to display the values that you want with charts modules, but how can I do some operations over that values so I can display advanced charts; like my case where I need to display the progress in percents over time. I know that you can add the field Global math to do some calculations, but is it possible to implement more advanced functions? And how can we do that? I didn't find to much info about this subject.